# detect doubleclick on NSTableview header

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, header, nstableview

i would need to detect a doubleclick on a `NSTableView`'s header.

i found the following that triggers on doubleclick, but i am unable to detect on what column has been clicked:

```
[table setTarget:self];
[table setDoubleAction:@selector(myDoubleClickInList:)];
```

and inside myDoubleClickInList: method i use

```
[table clickedRow] == -1
```

to get the header.

but i am unable to get the column identifier from `[table clickedColumn]`
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have access the an instance variable or property called `table` then the following will let you get the column identifier,

```
NSInteger column = [table clickedColumn];
NSRange columnRange = NSMakeRange(0, [table numberOfColumns]);
if (NSLocationInRange(column, columnRange){
    NSTableColumn *tableColumn = [[table tableColumns] objectAtIndex:column];
    NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
    // Now do something with the column identifier...

} else {
    // The click was not in a column, do something else...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If i had to do this, i'd create a `UIview` subclass with `UITapGestureRecognizer` (double tap -> selector) added on top of view, and in `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` returned that custom view. I cant provide you any code right now though, still i hope this'd be helpful.

Comment: or, if default table section view is good enough for you, why wont you add that gesture recognizer to the view in `viewForHeaderInSection:` ?

Comment: ehm, sorry forgot to mention that i am on osx not ios... will this work anyway?

Comment: Clearly the whole problem was not read. No, that answer won't work on OS X.